# How can I look for a certain pixel colour on my screen, in a specific area using Python's PIL?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

How can I look for a certain pixel colour on my screen, in a specific area using Python's PIL?

I need a function that will initiate a command in Python 2.7, if a certain pixel colour appears in a pre-designated area. I have tried the following code, with no avail:

```
def game_one():
box = (x_pad+1, y_pad+1, x_pad+1179, y_pad+474)
im = ImageGrab.grab(box)
return im
rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
for x in range(1055, 1120, 1):
    for y in range(20, 464, 1):
        pix = rgb_im.getpixel((x, y))
        if pix != (255,0,255):
            startPlaying()
            time.sleep(.2)
            clickbuttonone()
            print "Pixel Found!"
        else:
            print "Waiting for pixel to appear"
```

(The x_pad and y_pad are predefined screen variables - do not relate to the problem, but help to capture the whole screen)

ImageOps and Image are already imported, as is win32api and win32con.

Many thanks!

Comment: This code searches the designated area once.  Are you trying to search until the specified color is found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To search until the pixel is found, you can use a loop.  However, by nature it will be an infinite loop, which is bad practice.  I'm adding a timeout of 120 seconds (2 minutes) which you can adjust as is reasonable.

```
import time
pf = False   #check if pixel was found
start_time = time.time()

def game_one():
    box = (x_pad+1, y_pad+1, x_pad+1179, y_pad+474)
    im = ImageGrab.grab(box)
    # return im
    rgb_im = im.convert('RGB')
    while (pf == False) and ((time.time()-start_time) < 120):
        for x in range(1055, 1120, 1):
            if pf == True:
                break
            for y in range(20, 464, 1):
                pix = rgb_im.getpixel((x, y))
                if pix != (255,0,255):
                    startPlaying()
                    time.sleep(.2)
                    clickbuttonone()
                    print "Pixel Found!"
                    pf = True
                    break
                else:
                    print "Waiting for pixel to appear"
```

Also, make sure you check your indentation--it's probably just for posting on this site but the function definition *should not* be on the same line as the rest of the function.

**EDIT:**  Okay I think I found the major issue.  Do you see where I commented out `return im`?  A return statement *ends your function* and nothing after it will be processed.  Your code wasn't even getting to your `for` loops.  Try this.  That's why it was printing that weird type thing, because that's what you were returning!

Comment: No it doesn't :(
doesn't seem to want to integrate on its own, and when i run the function game_one() separately, it churns out the following:


<Image.Image image mode=RGB size=1440x900 at 0x25A6A30>

p.s.,  it's doesn't even print "Waiting for pixel to appear"

Comment: I didn't actually use your whole code which may have been more confusing than I intended. Let me edit it when I get to a computer and hopefully make it easier to understand.

Comment: I think I figured it out.  Or at least some of it.  Check out the edited answer.

Comment: Ok, I have tried again, the code seems to work now (be processed by python), however the pix function doesn't seem to want to recognise the x and y ranges - it works if i give it a set two numerical coordinates to find a colour at; e.g. ((1,2)), but for some reason not with ((x,y)) :(

Comment: To make sure that the `((x,y))` part is indeed what isn't working; since you found that it works at `((1,2))`, can you change your range to include `((1,2))`?  My only thought here is that it might be searching a different area than you think it is (since we know that it works in a discrete case).  I'd check your pixel ranges just to be sure, although you've probably already done this.  **edit:** You could also check the dimensions of the image you grab to make sure it is indeed getting the correct image.